# Getting the 'cannot read property style of null'

Tags: javascript

Please review my code. I tried a lot but I couldn't find the problem. How do I prevent such errors in the future?

```
<script>
var tbox= document.getElementById('tbox');
var selector= document.getElementById('selector');
function change(tothis){
    tbox.style.color=tothis;
}
function appear(){
    selector.style.visibility='visible';
    tbox.focus();
}
function disappear(){
    selector.style.visibility='hidden';
}
setTimeout(disappear,500);
</script>
```

Comment: looks like the elements are not there

Answer (score 1):

the error means that either `tbox` or `selector` doesn't exist.

`document.getElementById('tbox');` is looking for an element with a id of tbox:

i.e. `<p id="tbox"></p>`

check that an element exists. if it does look at the code and its placement on the document. If the script is in the `head` then the element wont exist yet.

make sure your code is after the html element in the dom or use a doc ready block